# Display stored database image on webpage using session?

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, mysqli

Hi I'm trying to store image into database using session and its successfully done but problem is that its can't display on my webpage when I upload the page and click on save button the previous pic display again but the new pic save into database successfully  and I want to store the pic on my folder also the coding is as following

**The Html page coding is as following**

```
<form class="form" action="accountsetting.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto mb-3">
            <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 140px;">
                <div class="rounded-circle avatar avatar-xl mb-3">
                    <img class="rounded-circle" id="preview_avatar" name="image" src="https://imgbob.com/path/cdn/avatars /zxMvnv1q52hFyNeEGKz0UuPU5fkth5YadkXe3m26S4HODj09An.png"  
width="100" height="100">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between mb-3">
            <div class="text-center text-sm-left mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                <h4 class="pt-sm-2 pb-1 mb-0 text-nowrap"><?php echo $_SESSION['user']['fullname']; ?></h4>
                                                                                            <p class="mb-0"><?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username']; ?></p>
                <div class="form-group mb-2 pt-2">
                    <input class='input' type='hidden' name='id' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id']; ?>" />
                    <input id="avatar" type="file" name="avatar" hidden="" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg">
                    <button id="uploadBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-file " >
                        <i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp Upload Avatar
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end pr-5">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit" name="profile">Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**The PHP coding is as following**

```
$id = "";
if(isset($_POST['profile'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $file=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"]));
    $query = "UPDATE users SET avatar = '$file' WHERE id = '$id'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($db,$query);

    if($query_run) {
        echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> alert("image profile upload")</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> alert("image profile not upload")</script>';
    }
}
```

**Session from HTML page side**

```
<?php
include('../functions.php');
if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header("location: /uploadimg/loginform.php");
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    header("location: /uploadimg/loginform.php");
}
if(isset($_SESSION['success']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['success'];
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['fullname']))
{

}
?>
```

**Session from PHP page side**

```
<?php 
session_start();

function isAdmin()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin' ) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Is you `addslashes()` to the binary you read from disk, you will undoubtably corrupt the file

Comment: It is normal to `base64_encode()` an image file before trying to store it on a database. Image files are complex files and can often contain data that looks like an end-of-file marker which is not at the end of the file

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: dear can you solve this problem for me please